# Spring Cloud Function (GCP adapter) throws Hibernate lazy could not initialize proxy - no session

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, gson, spring-cloud-function

This is a common error in **Spring** when tries to transform automatically an entity object whit some hibernate proxys but i dont't know how to load **Jackson DataType Hibernate5** module in **Spring cloud functions gcp adapter**.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Log4j2
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        log.info("configurando cors");
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Module datatypeHibernateModule() {
        log.info("Cargando modulo hibernate jackson");
        return new Hibernate5Module();
    }
}
```

If i use the same code whit normal **Spring boot** project the module works but in this case i found on the log the adapter don't used **Jackson** and they implements **Gson**.

```
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.json.GsonMapper.toJson(GsonMapper.java:70)
```

[This is the entire log file](https://gist.github.com/ripper2hl/ea18dda60861b3381a45fef6916b7cae)

My first workaround is change the Page object for String and use manually jackson mapper.

```java
public class ObtenerEstados implements Function<Void, String> {
    
    @Autowired
    private EstadoService estadoService;
    
    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String apply(Void unused) {
        Page<Estado> page = estadoService.buscarTodos(0, 33);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
        String objectAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(page);
        return objectAsString;
    }
}
```

I created two branches on the Github repository

- [functions (this branch have the bug)](https://github.com/ripper2hl/sepomex/tree/functions)
- [function-jackson-hibernate5 (this branch have the workaround)](https://github.com/ripper2hl/sepomex/tree/function-jackson-hibernate5)

If you haved already installed Docker and Docker Compose you can reproduce the bug easy.

Follow the next steps:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/ripper2hl/sepomex.git

cd sepomex 

git checkout -b dev origin/functions

docker-compose pull db

docker-compose up -d db

export spring_profiles_active=local

mvn -Pgcp function:run
```

And execute with a curl or any REST client

```sh
curl http://localhost:8080/
```

I know the alternative for use a DTO object but i prefer not use this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whenever Gson is on the classpath it is given priority and of course with Google that is the case. Please set `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=jackson` property to force Jackson.

Comment: Can you please provide a full stack trace?

Comment: Actually i see that the GCP guys have an open issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/570 to enable Jackson. I'll reach out to them

Comment: I am fixing it!

Comment: wow very cool, thank you for the fix, if you still need the complete stacktrace this is the link 

https://gist.github.com/ripper2hl/ea18dda60861b3381a45fef6916b7cae

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed with this fragment of code

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
        JacksonMapper jacksonMapper = new JacksonMapper(objectMapper);
        return new JsonMessageConverter(jacksonMapper);
    }
}
```

The documentation explain Gson is the default MessageConverter but it's not be clear how to change(more easy) gson to jackson.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_provided_messageconverters

Comment: The above is a good workaround, but in any event, [the issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/570) is fixed and backported and will be available in the next release.